# String copy- basics

Tags: c, arduino

Is this code good?

```
void function (char* reqData) {
    char serverData[130]={0};
    uint8_t buffer[128] = {0};
    uint32_t len = wifi.recv(&mux_id, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 100);

    //fill the serverData in some for loop
     for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
           serverData[i]=(char)buffer[i];

    serverData[len ] = '\0';
    strcpy(reqData,serverData);       // * my concern !
}
```

and in the main , using with :

```
//some global var
char *incomingData={0};

//then 

function(incomingData);
```

Its causing me problems that I can't explain (strange crashes on the hardware)

Comment: where is `len` defined and how do you know `reqData` will fit in `serverData` ? also you seem to be passing null into the function and then strcpy from there.. post sufficient code so these are explained. also strcpy is defined strcpy(destination, source)..

Comment: thanks, i have edited the question ..

Comment: note that this just leads to the question - where is wifi defined ? if you post an entire replicable program with your issue people will actually be able to help you

Comment: well, its a big chunk of code that i dont think i can put here, but i was wondering if whats now on my question , has some serious  bugs that you can see..

Comment: ideally you should reduce the code down to something minimal and runnable. so the issue can be replicated and solved

Comment: `incomingData` as global variable is not *malloc'd*, the crashes you're seeing is a  manifestation of the issue when attemping to copy `serverData` into a buffer via `strcpy`.

Comment: got it. thanks a lot. fixing it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here

```
strcpy(reqData,serverData);       // * my concern !
```

`reqData` is pointing to where `incomingData` is pointing:

```
char *incomingData={0};
```

But you have not initialized `incomingData` properly, it is not pointing to a memory where you can write something. Also ={0} initialization of pointer seems a bit weird to me. You can have it initialized like this below - if you know size in advance.

```
char incomingData[SIZE] = {0};
```

Also inside function:

```
char serverData[130]={0};
```

`serverData` has length 130 be careful of buffer overflow, what if on the next lines you receive data that is larger than 130?

Comment: thanks a lot . So what exactly i do the fix this ? How should i initialise it ?

Comment: @Curnelious: There is no necessity; if you want it to be pointer, assign to it sufficient memory returned by malloc

Comment: thank you. you asked about data being > 130 . well it might happen. so what can i do to fix this ? ( i am not that into C , sorry if its a basic question)

Comment: @Curnelious: Is there way you can know the length ? After you know the length you can use malloc to allocate sufficient amount of bytes. Or instead 130 but number which you know will never be exceeded by number of bytes you receive

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Yes, it is not pointing to a meaningful place

Comment: I dont know it. but i lets assume i know it will never be bigger then 150. So is it "good" to declare incomingData to be 180 to cover it all ?

Comment: @Curnelious: Yes, that way is fine

Comment: @Giorgi: That's not the same as "not initialized".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Of course I know that, but that is being pedantic or how they call it :) I was planning to correct it anyway